# Unresolved reference: Platform, in multiplatform project

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have created a kotlin shared library project (using Android Studio on Windows), the android side of things work fine, but for some reason when writing iOS specific code in Kotlin, I can't seem to import the `platform` libraries. I was following the instructions from [here](https://mobiraft.com/android/kotlin/getting-started-with-kotlin-multiplatform/) to get started.

I did put `include ':Shared'` in my `settings.gradle` and also this    `implementation project(':Shared')` in my app `build.gradle`

My end goal is to have the library just have business logic that will be shared between iOS and Android. I'm just trying to get an example project running, so that I know it works.

This is how my file structure is:

[image: File structure]

My `build.gradle` for the `Shared` module:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-multiplatform'

/*We are doing three things in the codebase below:

   1.  Listing out the target for the shared code. For Android, JVM target.
       For iOS, target depends on the device type, i.e. simulator or a real device.

   2.  We have defined iOS, Android and common source sets, which will allow different
       configuration for each source set.

   3.  We have created a task for Xcode to generate framework and add it to our iOS project.
   */
kotlin{
    targets{
        //        //Xcode sets SDK_NAME environment variable - based on whether the
        //        //target device is a simulator or a real device, the preset should vary
        final def iOSTarget = System.getenv('SDK_NAME')?.startsWith("iphoneos") \
                               ? presets.iosArm64 : presets.iosX64


        //outputKinds - FRAMEWORK would mean that the shared code would be exported as a FRAMEWORK
        // EXECUTABLE - produces a standalone executable that can be used to run as an app
        fromPreset(iOSTarget, 'ios'){
            binaries{
                framework('Shared')
            }
        }

        //create a target for Android from presets.jvm
        fromPreset(presets.jvm, 'android')
    }

    //we have 3 different sourceSets for common, android and iOS.
    //each sourceSet can have their own set of dependencies and configurations
    sourceSets{
        commonMain.dependencies{
            api 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common'
        }
        androidMain.dependencies{
            api 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib'
            implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        }

        iosMain{

        }
    }
}
configurations{
    compileClasspath
}


// This task attaches native framework built from ios module to Xcode project
// Don't run this task directly,
// Xcode runs this task itself during its build process when we configure it.
// make sure all Gradle infrastructure exists (gradle.wrapper, gradlew)
//and gradlew is in executable mode (chmod +x gradlew)
task packForXCode(type: Sync) {
    final File frameworkDir = new File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    final String mode = project.findProperty("XCODE_CONFIGURATION")?.toUpperCase() ?: 'DEBUG'
    final def framework = kotlin.targets.ios.binaries.getFramework("Shared", mode)
    inputs.property "mode", mode
    dependsOn framework.linkTask
    from { framework.outputFile.parentFile }
    into frameworkDir
    doLast {
        new File(frameworkDir, 'gradlew').with {
            text = "#!/bin/bash\nexport 'JAVA_HOME=${System.getProperty("java.home")}'\ncd '${rootProject.rootDir}'\n./gradlew \$@\n"
            setExecutable(true)
        }
    }
}

tasks.build.dependsOn packForXCode

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

`commonMain` code:

```
//This function will be the general function declaration that will be used as
//actual in our platform specific code.
expect fun getCurrentDate() : String

//This is the common function that will be called by Android and iOS app
fun getDate():String{
    return "Current Date is ${getCurrentDate()}"
}
```

`androidMain` code:

```
import java.util.*

actual fun getCurrentDate(): String{
    return Date().toString()
}
```

`iosMain` code (this is where the issue is):

```
//can't get this import to work.
//import platform.Foundation.NSDate

actual fun getCurrentDate(): String{
   //return NSDate().toString()
    return ""
}
```

My android `MainActivity` (this works) :

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import getDate// function from our Shared Module

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.dateLbl).text = getDate()
    }
}
```

Any help or advice as to why the platform libraries won't work will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this on Windows, and the iOS platforms don't appear to be available, even just for importing. I don't think you'll be able to edit Apple targets on Windows. The available targets locally are:

```
android_arm32/
android_arm64/
android_x64/
android_x86/
linux_arm32_hfp/
linux_arm64/
linux_x64/
mingw_x64/
mingw_x86/
```

You can see local targets here: `~/.konan/kotlin-native-windows-1.3.72/klib/platform`

Comment: Hi, I saw that too, which is werid, because according to [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/platform_libs.html) article the platform libraries are available by default. No special link flags need to be specified to use them. Kotlin/Native compiler automatically detects which of the platform libraries have been accessed and automatically links the needed libraries.

Comment: ~/..konan\kotlin-native-windows-1.3.72/konan/platformDef/ios contains some of the packages of iOS such as the UIKit.dfef and posix.def etc. Maybe something with that can work?

Comment: Even to use `posix` we need platform :  `import platform.posix.*`